# Checking username & password using form authentication in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I'm trying to write a method that authenticate a user in the web apps. Here is the code:

```
public void SignIn(UserInfo Entity)
    {
        if(this.CheckUser(Entity.UserName, Entity.Password))

        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Entity.UserName, false);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    public bool CheckUser(String _UserName, string _Password)
    {
        using (var context = new TourBlogEntities1())
        {
            List<UserInfo> test = null;
            test = (from s in context.UserInfoes
                       where s.UserName == _UserName && s.Password == _Password
                       select s).ToList<UserInfo>();

            if(test==null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

    }
```

The problem is I can sign in with any username & password, which are not actually registered. What I have done wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is never null. You need to check whether your list contains a element.

I suggest you use the `Any()` or `Count()` method.

> **Any()** - Determines whether a sequence contains any elements.
>
> **Count()** - Returns a number that represents how many elements in the specified sequence satisfy a condition.

### Sample

#### Any()

```
return (from s in context.UserInfoes
       where s.UserName == _UserName && s.Password == _Password
       select s).Any();
```

#### Count()

```
return (from s in context.UserInfoes
       where s.UserName == _UserName && s.Password == _Password
       select s).Count() != 0;
```

### More Information

- [MSDN - Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx)
- [MSDN - Enumerable.Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx)

Comment: Sorry for being late to mark as correct, thanks for your help.